# Should I not use this string-byte type casting assembly code?

Tags: solidity, remix, assembly

My string to bytes32, bytes32 to string code is below.

```
  function _stringToBytes32(string _string)
    internal
    pure
    returns (bytes32 _bytes32)
  {
    require(bytes(_string).length < 33);
    assembly {
      _bytes32 := mload(add(_string, 0x20))
    }
  }

  function _bytes32ToString(bytes32 _bytes32)
    internal
    pure
    returns (string _string)
  {
    assembly {
      let m := mload(0x40)
      mstore(m, 0x20)
      mstore(add(m, 0x20), _bytes32)
      mstore(0x40, add(m, 0x40))
      _string := m
    }
  }
```

I find the warning from remix,

> static analysis modules do not parse inline Assembly, this can lead to wrong analysis results.

And on [solidity document](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/assembly.html#solidity-assembly),

> Statically-sized memory arrays do not have a length field, but it will be added soon to allow better convertibility between statically- and dynamically-sized arrays, so please do not rely on that.

It seems that this is not the case of my code.
However, I want to know how much risk is relying on this assembly code.

My functions are rely on two facts,

1. Under 33 length alphanumeric string has 32bytes length field +
   32bytes body field.
2. Bytes32 has 32bytes body field only.

Comment: I believe that the static analysis warning is just saying that it can't tell if there's anything wrong in that function because it doesn't understand assembly. "Sorry, you're on your own"-style.